# Lee's algorithm - finding characters in table

Tags: c#, grid

I have problem to find the shortest path between two squares in the grid.

I would like to implement Lee's algorithm, but my struggle is to find the neighbors of specific coordinate in the table.

What I am not quite sure, where to move the cursor in the grid, when I label the neighbors with specific number. I have four movements in the grid, so I label everytime four neighbors of the current point, but where to move then?

Example:

My input:

Size of the grid: MxN

Characters which would be in the table. For example ABCDEF...(It is sort of Keyboard)

String which would be written by the table:

For example: BCD

Output of the program would be minimum of presses to write this specific string. 
Start position of the cursor in the grid is in upper left corner. Presses are: up, down, left, right and ENTER - which will print the character

My starting aproach is: First find the position of the character of the string in the table. Then make a matrix with distances, which has in the beginning everywhere zeros. Then check if the character, which was found, is in upper left corner. If is, then number of presses is 1, find another character. Else label neighbors and get to the current letter. If you get to the current letter save number of presses and find next character from the position of the previous character.

Answer (score 0):

See my button project below.  Read comments.  You can implement with a textboxes so you can put letters into the boxes, or a picture box where yo can added pictures to the cells.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Buttons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 5;
        const int COLS = 10;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new MyButton(ROWS, COLS, this);
        }


    }
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        const int WIDTH = 50;
        const int HEIGHT = 50;
        const int SPACE = 5;
        const int BORDER = 20;

        public static List<List<MyButton>> buttons { get; set; }
        public static List<MyButton> buttonList { get; set; }
        public Form1 form1;
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int col { get; set; }
        public Boolean[] neighbors { get; set; }  //array 0 to 3, 0 top, 1 right, 2 bottom, 3 left with false is no wall true is wall 
        public MyButton()
        {
        }
        public MyButton(int rows, int cols, Form1 form1)
        {
            buttons = new List<List<MyButton>>();
            buttonList = new List<MyButton>();

            this.form1 = form1;
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                List<MyButton> newRow = new List<MyButton>();
                buttons.Add(newRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                {
                    MyButton newButton = new MyButton();
                    newButton.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newButton.Width = WIDTH;
                    newButton.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.Left = col * (WIDTH + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.row = row;
                    newButton.col = col;
                    newRow.Add(newButton);
                    buttonList.Add(newButton);
                    newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);
                    form1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                }
            }
            neighbors = new Boolean[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
            {
                neighbors[i] = true;
            }
        }
        public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyButton button = sender as MyButton;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Pressed Button Row {0} Column {1}", button.row, button.col));

        }

    }
}
```